# How to disable scrollbind and cursorbind after using vimdiff?

Tags: split, vimdiff, cursor, scrolling

I have this issue where I need to both compare files, which I do using `vimdiff`, but also work on individual files with vertically split screens (`vs`). However, after I call vimdiff on a file, opening the file again later I see that `scrollbind` and `cursorbind` are set, which gets annoying to deactivate manually all the time. Is there a way to turn off `scrollbind` and `cursorbind` off automatically on exit form vimdiff?

As a clarification, here's an example of what I experience:

```
$ vim foo.txt             # works fine, noscrollbind and nocursorbind are set
$ vimdiff foo.txt bar.txt # works as expected, scrollbind and cursorbind are set during diff
$ vim foo.txt             # now scrollbind and cursorbind remain set, which I don't want
```

Comment: See if `:diffoff` solves the problem. Will post an answer if it works for you. Add `!` if you want it to effect all windows (in current tabpage).

Comment: It doesn't. Also I know how to `set noscrollbind` and `set nocursorbind`, but I don't want to do it every time manually, as the steps I outlined above are part of a workflow that I use very often.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it.

Comment: That didn't change the outcome either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126556/discussion-between-b-layer-and-mivkov).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a command that is made to deal with exactly that: `:diffoff`

It's effect on the *current window*...

```
    'diff'      off
    'scrollbind'    off
    'cursorbind'    off
    'scrollopt' without "hor"
    'wrap'      on
    'foldmethod'    "manual"
    'foldcolumn'    0
```

In other words it reverses all the settings put in place by `:diff`.

Now in your case we've encountered a bit trickiness. The command isn't working for you, you've reported, and that's apparently due to the fact that you're running the diff from the command line with `vimdiff`.

Fortunately, there's a variation of the command that will extend its effects to *all windows* (in the current tabpage): `:diffoff!` (the difference is the bang `!` appended to the command). You've reported success with this.

**Update:** Ah, thanks to DBK's insightfulness we've solved the mystery of why `'scrollbind'` and `'cursorbind'` are getting preserved when a previously closed diff'ed file is reopened. (Which don't sound right.)

@mivkov is actually doing `mkview` in an autocommand and thus those two settings are persisted. The key line is basically this:

```
autocmd BufWinLeave * mkview
```

And, fortuitously, this actually lends itself to a bonus for the OP...an easy way to automate the running of `:diffoff` which they weren't too keen on doing manually. Problem solved with a bit of a modification to that auto command:

```
autocmd BufWinLeave * if &diff | diffoff | endif | mkview
```

And everyone goes home happy!